# Redirect root to another folder but anything else to app router

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess

Not sure if what I want can even be done and I found many things here that are close, but not quite there. I want/need to redirect the root URL (/) to a wordpress site running in it's own sub-folder in the web root. Using:

```
RewriteEngine on
# our root gets redirected to wordpress
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://mysubdomain.com
```

...that works fine. Then for anything besides root (e.g. example.com/somepath), I need index.html in the root to handle it. This is the entry point for a Vue JS app with it's own router. I tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
# our root gets redirected to wordpress
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://mysubdomain.com
# anything else load our app (index.html in the web root)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,QSA]
```

...but that causes a too many redirects error in the bowser. I tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
# our root gets redirected to wordpress
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://mysubdomain.com
# anything else load our app (index.html in the web root)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.html [L,QSA]
```

... and that almost works expcept the paths have a literal index.html in them instead of just the urls paths. The goal is to have anything other that the root path go to that literal path via hte Vue JS app in the web root (through index.html I think). So if one goes to `http://example.com/somepath` the browser location should be that path process via the Vue JS router.

Hope that makes sense. Any thoughts or ideas? I also know I could redirect to a sub-folder with the Vue JS app in it, but that is not what the client wants unless that sub-folder can be excluded from the URL.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

We opted to redirect using the Vue JS app router so that the root url (/) does a JS redirect in favor of trying to redirect via .htaccess. Issue is resolved.